# Is moderator notified about an edit on a deleted post?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I wonder if the moderator who deleted my post will be notified that I have edited my post? Or it's just useless and i need to make another answer?

Comment: No, they won't be. Why was it deleted?

Comment: Do you have a link to your deleted post?

Comment: I'm not sure if my answer was just bad, or if my idea to say how resolve the problem is not a good thing on stackoverflow : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631154/getting-segmentation-fault-after-completion-of-program)

Comment: Don't answer bad questions, flag to close them.  If you don't have enough reputation to comment, don't answer as a comment, go get more reputation.

Comment: Your answer was inappropriate. You used the answer space to bypass not having comment privileges, which is against the site guidelines. The space headed *Your Answer* is for precisely that purpose - posting an answer to the question - and not to sneak around the requirement to have earned the privilege of commenting. (And you used it intentionally because you didn't have comment privileges - you posted a comment to your own answer that says so.)

Comment: Okay, i'll keep that in mind thanks. But even if i said it in a comment, it was just because people said it has to be a comment. And now i don't think so.

Comment: Undeleted because you do *attempt* to answer the question now. It's not a great answer, and it's a pretty terrible question. In the future, put more effort into your answers and don't answer bad questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A moderator will **not** be notified if you've edited a post that they deleted.

If you feel that you've adequately addressed the problem(s) that caused your post to be deleted, and feel that it now merits undeletion, you can flag the post for moderator attention and explain why you feel the post now merits undeletion.

If you simply wish to speak with the moderator more about why your post was deleted, you can either go to the chatroom and ask to chat with a mod about why your post was deleted (or whatever else you want to talk with them about related to the issues) or, if you feel comfortable discussing it publicly, you can ask a question here on meta about your deleted post.

Comment: Can users flag their own posts without 15 rep? I've never bothered testing it.